# VBA Range variable gone after cut

Tags: excel, vba, range

424 error. Would anyone be kind enough to tell me why the range variable was gone after cut?

```
with sheets(1)
Dim des as range
set des = .range("A15")
.range("A1:A3").cut des
msgbox(des.row+5)
end with
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Range` object stores a reference to particular cells, not to particular address. When the referenced cells move around, the `Range` object will follow. E.g. if you store a `Range("B1")` and then insert a column between A and B, your variable will now have `Range("C1")`, because your `B1` has moved to the right.

When the tracked cells cease to exist, the `Range` instance becomes unusable.

Cutting replaces the actual cells entirely as opposed to simply overwriting their contents, so the cell your `Range` is tracking stops to exist, and some other cell will now assume the address of `A15`. That is a different cell though, so your `Range` instance is gone.

A notable exception is when you destroy only a part of the `Range`. In that case the `Range` accepts the new cells and maintains its shape. E.g. if you stored `Range("A15:A20")` and cut `Range("A1:A3")` over `A15`, the resulting range would still be `A15:A20`.

Comment: Doesn't copy also alter the targeted cell? .range("A1:A3").copy des
msgbox(des.row+5) would work just fine.

Comment: @KuanChunYeh It alters their state, not their existence. If you store `A1:A3` into another variable, e.g. `source As Range`, you will see that after `Cut` `source` moves to `A15:A17`, but after `Copy` it stays at `A1:A3`.

Comment: Wow. You're exactly right even though state and existence sound like a philosophy question. May I know the simplest way to keep track of the same address?

Comment: @KuanChunYeh In all fairness, that sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640), because the moving ranges is actually what you want most of the time (in fact, all the time in my personal experience). If you do have a valid reason to track an address in this absolute fashion, then store the address as a string and resolve it to a range each time you need it.

Comment: thanks for the trick. it wouldn't let me store the address as a string and resolve it to a range. what i did was "dim des as a string des="Sheets(1).Range("A15")" sou.Cut .Range(des)" would you mind showing me the correct way?

Comment: @KuanChunYeh `Dim des as string : des = "A15" : sou.Cut .Range(des)`.

Comment: my des is actually something like .range("K"& . range("j9").end(xldown).row). May I know the best way to set it up as a string and range it?

Comment: @KuanChunYeh `des = "K" & .Range("j9").End(xlDown).Row`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `.paste` is clearing the range variable for @GSerg reason.

Using this code works, but if you break it at the end, the variable exists until the paste has happened.

```
With Sheets(1)
    Set des = .Range("A15")
    .Range("A1:A3").Cut
    des.Cells(1, 1).Select
    MsgBox (des.Row + 5)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
```

If you move the message box to after the paste, it clears `des` even though it's not being used in the cut as yours did.

I will do some more investigation.  The `des` object still exists as a `range` but just unpopulated.

This method also does what cut would do

```
Dim src As Range
Dim des As Range

With Sheets(1)

    Set src = .Range("a1:a3")
    Set des = .Range("a15")
    des.Resize(src.Rows.Count, src.Columns.Count).Value = src.Value
    src.Clear

End With
```

Comment: eventually i used the same alternative by copying and clearing.