# I keep getting an object required on my code. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sorry if this is a really basic question, but I've been grappling with it for ages and cannot figure it out.

Why does my code keep giving an object required error?

```
Sub MatchUp()

    For Each PastCell In Range("A1:A240")
        For Each FutureCell In Range("P1:P240")
            If FutureCell.Value = PastCell.Value Then
                Range(FutureCell.Offset(0, 1), FutureCell.Offset(0, 9)).Cut _
                        Range(PastCell.Offset(0, 15), PastCell.Offset(0.23))
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you `Offset` by `0.23` rows? I'm not sure I understand what that's supposed to be doing.

Comment: @Comintern - perhaps a typo, and OP meant `...Offset(0, 23)`?  Also, OP, can you explain what you're trying to do with this macro? There may be a better way to do this - are you just trying to move data?

Comment: I'm a complete idiot. Thank you!

Comment: Bruce, yes, I'm basically just moving data. Can be done far more easily via vlookup, but wanted to try doing it via vba.

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, @Comintern But It is not clear to me why correcting `PastCell.Offset(0.23)` is  removing  the error in line  `If FutureCell.Value = PastCell.Value Then`. Asked only in academic interest.

Comment: @AhmedAU TBH, I didn't even check to see if that was the source of the error - it would effectively be no offset though, so the the second range is 15 rows and the first one is only 9.

Comment: Also, you should declare your variables. Perhaps just adding `Dim pastCell as Range, futureCell as Range` will help?

Comment: @AnoniMoose why not just use the vlookup in the VBA? Unless this is simply for educational purposes for yourself, looping through two ranges is likely to be a bit slower/more taxing than just running the formula. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple type-o's, plus it's better to avoid copy/paste. See below. There's cleaner ways of doing this, but this (untested) code should get you to the finish line...

```
Sub MatchUp()
Dim pastCell As Range, FuturCell As Range


    For Each pastCell In Range("A1:A240").Cells
        For Each FutureCell In Range("P1:P240").Cells
            If FutureCell.Value = pastCell.Value Then
                Range(pastCell.Offset(0, 15), pastCell.Offset(0, 23)).Value = Range(FutureCell.Offset(0, 1), FutureCell.Offset(0, 9)).Value
                Range(FuturCell.Offset(0, 1), FuturCell.Offset(0, 9)).ClearContents

            End If
        Next FuturCell
    Next pastCell
End Sub
```