# VBA For Each ... Loop skipping cells when clearing row

Tags: excel, vba

I know this is a common problem people have when trying to delete rows when looping through ranges but that is not the case here. Rather than deleting the rows, I am cutting the entire row and pasting into another worksheet, leaving a blank row. The issue is that the For Each ... Loop acts as if I deleted the row and skips the next cell in the loop. Below is a snippet of the code.

```
last_row = 100

Set search_rng = n_ws.Range(n_ws.Range("L2"), n_ws.Cells(last_row, 12))

    For Each cell In search_rng
        find_amt = cell.Value * -1
        Set s_cell = search_rng.Find(find_amt, LookIn:=xlFormulas)

        If Not s_cell Is Nothing Then
            ' do stuff
        Else
            'No matching value found, move row to o_ws
            paste_row = o_ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            n_ws.Rows(cell.Row).Cut o_ws.Cells(paste_row, 1).EntireRow  
        End If
    Next
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I imagine I can fix it by changing the For Each ... Loop to a For i in Range loop but I'm more curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: Cutting the row still deletes it. You want to copy and paste, then clear contents of your row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Range variable gone after cut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54021851/11683)

Answer (score 3):

Cutting the row still deletes it in pratice. You can convince yourself of this by just manually doing so on the spread sheet. You will see a shift in range which means this is the same issue as deleting rows in a loop. A common way to avoid this issue would be to switch to `For i` loop and loop backwards.

Since you are not actually deleting rows here you could also try the following....

Using your same code, you can just copy & paste the row, **not cut**, and then circle back around and clear the rows content to leave a blank row in place.

```
   Else
        paste_row = o_ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        n_ws.Rows(Cell.Row).Copy o_ws.Cells(paste_row, 1)
        n_ws.Rows(Cell.Row).ClearContents
    End If

Next cell
```

---

### Note

The better way to do this would be to loop through your range and create a `Union` (*collection of cells*) that meet your criteria. Once the loop is done you can copy, paste, & clear the `Union` all at once. This means you have **one** instance of actions taken to worksheet rather many